# Unable to import static android.support.test.espresso.contrib.DrawerMatchers.isOpen;

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I am using espresso for testing my android application. When am trying to write test cases for navigation drawer menu am unable to import any of these

```
import static android.support.test.espresso.contrib.DrawerActions.closeDrawer;
import static android.support.test.espresso.contrib.DrawerActions.openDrawer;
import static android.support.test.espresso.contrib.DrawerMatchers.isClosed;
import static android.support.test.espresso.contrib.DrawerMatchers.isOpen;
```

So please help me from this

Answer (score 18):

You may missing in `build.gradle` `espresso-contrib`dependencies like below:

```
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2"
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2"
/**
 * AccessibilityChecks
 * CountingIdlingResource
 * DrawerActions
 * DrawerMatchers
 * PickerActions (Time and Date picker)
 * RecyclerViewActions
 */
androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

Hope it will help