# How to write test cases for navigation drawer menu using espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am very new to espresso and am trying to write test cases for my android application. I searched on google to write test cases for navigation drawer menu. But in that am unable to import

```
 import static android.support.test.espresso.contrib.DrawerActions.closeDrawer;
import static android.support.test.espresso.contrib.DrawerActions.openDrawer;
import static android.support.test.espresso.contrib.DrawerMatchers.isClosed;
import static android.support.test.espresso.contrib.DrawerMatchers.isOpen;
```

so please help me from this. thanks in advance

Comment: check answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014465/unable-to-import-static-android-support-test-espresso-contrib-drawermatchers-iso/40056390#40056390

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your `app/build.gradle` file these dependencies:

```
androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
    exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

Hope it will help